# Setting null in list cause null value in other list

Tags: c#, collections

I have two lists which i want to get the different items from them

```
SearchElement[] criteria = new SearchElement[] { 
    new SearchElement 
    { 
         Comparison = "=", 
         FieldName = "CableProperty.ProjectId", 
         FieldValue = int.Parse(comboBoxSource.SelectedValue.ToString()), 
         LogicalOperator = "" }
     };

sourceCables = client.GetCables(criteria, null, "Cores,CableProperty,CableProperty.CableApplication").ToList();
criteria = new SearchElement[] { 
     new SearchElement 
     { 
         Comparison = "=", 
         FieldName = "CableProperty.ProjectId", 
         FieldValue = int.Parse(comboBoxDestination.SelectedValue.ToString()), 
         LogicalOperator = "" }
     };

destinationCables = client.GetCables(criteria, null, "Cores,CableProperty,CableProperty.CableApplication").ToList();
diffCables = sourceCables.Except(destinationCables, new CableComparer())
                          .ToList();
```

Now I have the different items in `diffcable`. Sometimes i want to set 
`diffCable.CableProperty.CableApplication = null;`
but when i do that, all the navigation Porperty(CableApplication) in sourcelist is also set to null.
this is the code

```
if (destinationCableApplications.Contains(diffCable.CableProperty.CableApplication, new CableApplicationComparer()))
{
   criteria = new SearchElement[] { new SearchElement { Comparison = "=", FieldName = "ProjectId", FieldValue = int.Parse(comboBoxDestination.SelectedValue.ToString()), LogicalOperator = "" }};
   cableApplication = client.GetCableApplications(criteria, null, "").SingleOrDefault();
   diffCable.CableProperty.CableApplication = null;
}
```

excatly in after this line

```
diffCable.CableProperty.CableApplication = null;
```

all the

```
  sourcecables[0].CableProperty.CableApplication

  sourcecables[1].CableProperty.CableApplication

  .....

  sourcecables[100].CableProperty.CableApplication
```

are set to null

what should i do to not lose the navigation property in sourcelist when i set null to navigation property in diffcable ?

Comment: make deep copy, rather than shallow copy of list

Comment: Like Arun said, you can't copy objects like this. You're copying references, it's the same object in both lists. You need to make a new object with the same data and place in the new list.

Comment: what do you mean by deep copy?

Comment: internally they work like array, when you write List1 = List2; it only pass first address of List2 to List1 variable. this is shallow copy as now both variable pointing to same physical address, what you need is to create separate memory block for List1 which will hold values(not reference) of List2 items, i.e. DeepCopy

Comment: @nnmmss The correct way to handle deep copies in C# is to have your Cable class implement `ICloneable`. It then implements a `Clone()` method which creates a new object and copies all the properties of the original.

Comment: @Tobberoth : can you give an example of it?

Comment: @nnmmss This link should get you on the right track: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28952/Shallow-Copy-vs-Deep-Copy-in-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is using MemoryStream..
Here is a sample,

```
    [Serializable]
    public class temp
    {
       public int a;
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static T DeepClone<T>(T a)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<temp> list1 = new List<temp>();
            list1.Add(new temp { a = 1 });
            list1.Add(new temp { a = 2 });
            list1.Add(new temp { a = 3 });
            List<temp> list2 = DeepClone<List<temp>>(list1);
            list1[1].a = 4;
            Console.WriteLine(list2[1].a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Note: class must be Serializable.
This will work for all value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a copy by reference without realising it. Look into Cloning your objects or creating new lists.

```
List<int> newCopyList = new List<int>(originalList);
```